# Generate appropriate urls in multiple sub-domain hostname in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

I am developing a multi sub-domain web application in Symfony 2.

**Subdomains:**

- `admin.example.com` is the main hosting site.
- `member.example.com` is another sub-domain pointing to same source code.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html) here, I configured routing as below :

**Parent Routing for `member.example.com`:**

```
my_app_member:
    resource: "@member.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host:     "member.example.com"
```

Note : The above routing is the parent route config for all routes for `member.example.com` defined in `member.yml`.

**Now I have anoter route for `admin.example.com` : **

```
admin_user_mod:
    path:     /admin/new
    defaults: { _controller: "somecontroller" }
```

However if I have to generate a full url for the route `admin_user_mod` using code :

```
$modLink = $this->get("router")->generate('admin_user_mod');
```

The generated route path is correct but the base url still stays as `member.example.com` which should be `admin.example.com`

Is there an way, or I am missing anything in above route configuration to get the desired results.

**OR**

Is there any symfony event listener to overwrite router's "`generate()`" method call?

All your inputs are highly appreciable.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Router has `getContext()` method you can use:

```
$context = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext();
$context->setHost('admin.example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin, Your suggestion working fine, But its needs to use each time I generate route. Is there any symfony event listener where I can use your code based on some routing match/condition?

Comment: @SunilKumar There is no such event. But you can implement your own UrlGenerator (maybe by extending [the symfony one's](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/master/Generator/UrlGenerator.php)?), put this logic there and inject it into your router by replacing `router` service.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [Routing Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls), passing true as the third parameter for the generate method will generate an absolute URL.

So in your case it would be...

```php
$modLink = $this->get('router')->generate('admin_user_mod', [], true);
```

Just make sure you specify the host in the route configuration when doing this. So for example your route should be...

```php
admin_user_mod:
    path: /admin/new
    host: admin.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: "somecontroller" }
```